# how do i get the filename of a duplicated saved file on django models?

Tags: python, django, model, view

When i upload a file with the same name the second one is uploaded with a different name like this:

```
First file: file.txt
Second file: file1YlQx18.txt
```

I want to get the name of the second file on a views.py 
because when i get the filename by method POST i just have file.txt

I'm using Django Rest Framework serializers

```
viewsets.py
from rest_framework import mixins
from rest_framework.viewsets import GenericViewSet


class CreateOnlyViewSet(mixins.CreateModelMixin, GenericViewSet):

    def pos_create(self, request):
        pass

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        r = super(CreateOnlyViewSet, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

    if r.status_code == 200 or r.status_code == 201:
        return self.pos_create(request)


serializers.py
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import MyModel

    class CareerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        class Meta:
            model = MyModel
            fields = '__all__'

views.py
from rest_framework.views import APIView    
from models import  MyModel
from .serializers import MyModelSerializer
from .viewsets import CreateOnlyViewSet


   class MyModelViewSet(CreateOnlyViewSet):
        model = MyModel
        serializer_class = MyModelSerializer

    def pos_create(self, request):
        serialized = MymodelSerializer(data=request.POST)
        #get name of the second file
```

Comment: and what does MymodelSerializer do? Which fields does MyModel has? How and where are you storing the files? Please post the code related to your question.

Comment: So you actually don't know this until after you save the file. The `request.POST` will only tell you what you sent over to Django. I suspect you're going to want to override [the `perform_create`](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/mixins.py#L25) and get a value back. And then put it in the response